# Why is My File->import menu option still disabled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

[image]

I added event handler to Import menu option and implemented action in code 
[image: How I added event handler]

```
  void CImportDial::OnFileImport32772()
    {
        CImportDial importDlg;
        importDlg.DoModal();
    }
void CImportDial::OnUpdateFileImport32772(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable();
    // TODO: Add your command update UI handler code here
}
```

but Import option is still disabled. Why?

Comment: Maybe you should show the rest? How did you add the event handler? And isn't there some sort of method that VS calls to determine whether the menu option should be enabled? Where is that?

Comment: I have just added second screen shot. What do you mean by "And isn't there some sort of method that VS calls to determine whether the menu option should be enabled? "?

Comment: Now that I see that (this is C++, right?) I can tell you that you need to implement UPDATE_COMMAND_UI.

Comment: I implemented this but it doesn't work yet. What exactly has to do it?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've done C++. What are the other methods of CCmdUI? Maybe that would give you a clue. But I don't remember anything else about this sort of thing in C++.

Comment: It didn't give me a clue. So I have to wait until someone else will answer.

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? Is this MFC? ATL? It's really been over a decade that I haven't used this stuff, so I really don't recall whose wizards those are. Adding the correct tag will help attract answers.